# Metatags quick - no output

Tags: 7, meta-tags

So I installed metatags quick module 7.x-2.3+3-dev on D7.12. Since my site is bilingual and I do not need any *per entity* variations, I decided to go the path-based way and checked the `Use path-based meta tags` checkbox. I created a path pattern, like `en/*`, for each language - as instructed: without leading or trailing slashes.

No go. In the source code the metas are not output.
I tried various formatters in the Manage Display sections, but to no avail.

What is the secret then? I bet it's something very obvious ;-)

Comment: In the "Create and Attach" section of the *admin/config/search/metatags_quick* page are the meta tags you want to output ticked in the row for "Path-based meta tags"?

Comment: Yep, they are: keywords, description and copyright. And they are in both rows when you click to expand. And by the way, should my custom metas (such as author) be tickable as well?